# if $a,b,c,d$ be the first positive solutions of $\sin x=\frac{1}{4}$ then...

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots

> if $a,b,c,d$ be the first positive solutions of $\sin x=\frac{1}{4}$ then find $$\sin (d/2)+2\sin (c/2)+3\sin (b/2)+4\sin (a/2)$$.$(a<b<c<d)$

**Attempts**
$$\sin x=1/4$$,$$4\sin^2(x/2)(1-\sin^2(x/2))=\frac{1}{16}$$
Let $\sin^2 (x/2)=t$:it remains to solve $$t-t^2=\frac{1}{64}$$ .The rest is just brute force i.e we calculate  the 4 values $\sin(x/2)$ can take , make sure the angles are arranged in ascending order and substitute the roots.As far as i can see i a getting irrational roots.

---

My question is does anyone spot a trick, that can avoid all this work.!

Comment: Are you sure that the expression to find is right? There's no $a$ involved

Comment: @Tortar typo! see now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $\sin a$ takes a positive value and $a$ is the smallest solution of $\sin x = \frac{1}{4}$, it follows that angle $a$ is between $0$ and $\frac{π}{2}$. This leads to the conclusion that $b=π−a, c=2π+a$ and $d=3π−a$.

Substituting these values in the original equation and using some basic trigonometric identities gives $2\sqrt{1+\sin a}.$

Comment: that was a good trick, i realise i went all around the bush.(+1)

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be simplified somewhat by looking at the geometry of the exercise with respect to the unit circle. The four half angles are distributed as in the diagram:

[image: distribution of half-angles about unit circle]

We see that $\sin(a/2)+sin(c/2)=0$ and $\sin(b/2)+\sin(d/2)=0$ which results in

$$\sin (d/2)+2\sin (c/2)+3\sin (b/2)+4\sin (a/2)=2\sin(a/2)+2\sin(b/2)$$

with much less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

So a is in the first quadrant

$b = \pi-a$

$c = a + 2\pi$

$d = 3\pi-a$

$\sin(\frac{b}{2}) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{a}{2}) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(-\frac{a}{2})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(-\frac{a}{2}) = \cos(\frac{a}{2})$

$\sin(\frac{c}{2}) = \sin(\frac{a}{2}+\pi) = \sin(\frac{a}{2})\cos(\pi)+\cos(\frac{a}{2})\sin(\pi) = -\sin(\frac{a}{2})$

$\sin(\frac{d}{2}) = \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{a}{2}) = \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})\cos(-\frac{a}{2})+\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2})\sin(-\frac{a}{2}) = -\cos(\frac{a}{2})$

So $\sin(\frac{d}{2}) + 2\sin(\frac{c}{2}) + 3\sin(\frac{b}{2}) + 4\sin(\frac{a}{2})$

$=2\sin(\frac{a}{2}) + 2\cos(\frac{a}{2})$

We know $\cos(a) = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{16}} = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$

Using the half-angle formla

$\sin(\frac{a}{2}) = \sqrt{0.5(1-\cos(a))}$

$\sin(\frac{a}{2}) = \sqrt{\frac{4-\sqrt{15}}{8}}$

similarly

$\cos(\frac{a}{2}) = \sqrt{\frac{4+\sqrt{15}}{8}}$

So

$2\sin(\frac{a}{2}) + 2\cos(\frac{a}{2}) = \sqrt{\frac{4-\sqrt{15}}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{4+\sqrt{15}}{2}}$

ok. simplifying the right side by squaring (comes out to 5) and then taking the square root, I get $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: i think you have miscalculated $\sin(c/2)$!

Comment: oops you're right.